# JSON Deserialization : Multiple object inside

Tags: asp.net, json

I have sample code ,that work fine.

```
public class Employee  
{  
    public int ID { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public string Address { get; set; }  
}  


   private void JSONDeserilaize()  
{  
    string json = @"{  
        'ID': '1',  
        'Name': 'Manas',  
        'Address': 'India'  
    }";  

    Employee empObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(json);  

    Response.Write(empObj.Name);  
}
```

But my json string is in this format.

```
string json = @"{"ID": "1","Name": "Manas","Address": "India","data":{"EmpDeptId":"20172807"}}";
```

How to fetch EmpDeptId along with Id,Name and Address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare another class for the object to deserialize into, then add it as a member of the original class:

```
public class Employee  
{  
    public int ID { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public string Address { get; set; } 
    public EmployeeData Data { get; set; } 
}

public class EmployeeData 
{
    public string EmpDeptId {get; set; }
}
```

It should then deserialize into `data` accordingly.

Comment: if you want Employee.EmpDeptId then add the line 
    public string EmpDeptId { get { return this.Data.EmpDeptId; set { this.Data.EmptDeptId = value  ; }  }    to Employee class

Comment: @IamSilviu Why would you do that? It's already a property of `Data`, you're then just repeating yourself in the object graph (it also could be serialised back to JSON). The OP can just do `employee.Data.EmptDeptId` to get the value.